# Custom event is not a function, Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am unable to execute a custom event using Puppeteer.

This is how my code looks like but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    headless: false,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.exposeFunction('getInfo', (event) => {
    console.log('getInfo');
  });

await page.goto('url');

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.document.getInfo(); // TypeError: window.document.getInfo is not a function
  });
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The method adds a function called name on the page's window object. When called, the function executes puppeteerFunction in node.js and returns a Promise which resolves to the return value of puppeteerFunction.

the key part is "on the page's window object". You're trying to find the function in `window.document` object.

This code should fix your problem:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.getInfo();
});
```

Also be aware that any such function returns a Promise, so you might want to do:

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await window.getInfo();
});
```

if your function should e.g. return something you want to later use inside `page.evaluate()` callback function.

See the [documentation for Puppeteer API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction).